# selected radio dropdown value in the inputfield instead of placeholder and show/hide dropdown when I click input field using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]I want dropdown with radio button which needs to show when I click  field and hide when I click outside and get the selected value in the inputfield.

**I need the selected value in the input field instead of placeholder value which I have and with show/hide dropdown when I click input field**

```html
<div className="inputWithIcon" onClick={this.RadioDdOnclick} id="radiobtn">
  <input className="inputBlock" id="radioSelect" type="text" placeholder="choose one" />
  <i className="fa fa-angle-down" />
</div>

<div className={ "BudgetRadioDd"} id={ "RadioDd"} style={{display: 'none'}}>
  <fieldset>
    <h4>options to choose</h4>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" id="1"/>option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> <input type="radio" id="2" />option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" id="3"/>option 3</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Not sure how to get this done using reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this in React:

You can attach a ref to the `<input>` to access it from the parent component, then check if the `<input>` is focused. If it is focused render the radio buttons, else don't.

To show the value of the selected option in the input tag, store that value in the component's `state` then it's easy to track its value and share that value between the input and the radios.

Also I've added the `name` attribute to the radio inputs so that they work properly as radio buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FormComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            option: '',
            inputIsFocused: false
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        this.setState({option: value});
    }

    toggleRadio = event => {
        const { inputIsFocused } = this.state;
        this.setState({inputIsFocused: !inputIsFocused});
    }

    render() {
        const { option, inputIsFocused } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="inputWithIcon" id="radiobtn">
                    <input ref='input' value={ option } className="inputBlock" id="radioSelect" type="text" placeholder="choose one" onFocus={ this.toggleRadio } onFocusOut={ this.toggleRadio }/>
                    <i className="fa fa-angle-down" />
                </div>

                { inputIsFocused && (
                    <div className={ "BudgetRadioDd"} id={ "RadioDd"}>
                        <fieldset>
                            <h4>options to choose</h4>
                            <div>
                                <label><input name='option' type="radio" id="1" value="1" checked={ option === '1' } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>option 1</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label> <input name='option' type="radio" id="2" value="2" checked={ option === '2' } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>option 2</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label><input name='option' type="radio" id="3" value="3" checked={ option === '3' } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>option 3</label>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

A note on the above: I think there's an issue with `onFocusOut`, so that doesn't actually get fired. Also of note is that the `inputIsFocused` value used in `render` is not the one from `state`. This is because of the issue with `onFocusOut` so the value of `inputIsFocused` needs to come from referencing the DOM, but in order to trigger a rerender, the component's `state` needs to update.

Here's a snippet to show what it might look like (note that the value in the snippet does not update when when a button is selected, but that functionality is present in the React code):

```js
function hideRadio() {
    const radioDd = document.querySelector('.BudgetRadioDd');
    radioDd.classList.add('hidden');
}

function showRadio() {
    const radioDd = document.querySelector('.BudgetRadioDd');
    radioDd.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="inputWithIcon" onClick={this.RadioDdOnclick} id="radiobtn">
  <input class="inputBlock" id="radioSelect" type="text" placeholder="choose one" onfocus="showRadio();" onfocusout="hideRadio();"/>
  <i className="fa fa-angle-down" />
</div>

<div class="BudgetRadioDd hidden" id="RadioDd">
  <fieldset>
    <h4>options to choose</h4>
    <div>
      <label><input name='attributeName' type="radio" id="1"/>option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> <input name='attributeName' type="radio" id="2" />option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input name='attributeName' type="radio" id="3"/>option 3</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

However this seems like pretty much the functionality of a `<select>`, so maybe consider using one of those?

Comment: i want radio button before value "option 1". how can I do that in Select?

Comment: @Poosapati so like a button to show/hide the `<select>`?

Comment: no, when I click <input> field the dropdown show/hide should happen and selected value from the dropdown should appear in <input> field instead of placeholder.. attached link for references how my radio button and value needs to looks like in dropdown:  https://blog.prototypr.io/7-rules-of-using-radio-buttons-vs-drop-down-menus-fddf50d312d1

Comment: added the screenshot in the question

Comment: yeah I understand it is same has Select but the prblm with select is we can't customize much. I am trying this out in my code now will update you.

Comment: onFocusOut is not valid in react. we need to use onBlur() figuring out how to handle show/hide. My input value is rendering with selected value in dropdown.